# CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE

Tags: samba, cifs, smb

Linux: 4.18.0-305
OS: CentOS 8.4

I have an SMB folder that is mounted with the following command:

```
mount -t cifs -o iocharset=utf8,rw,credentials=${_passwordFile},nobrl,nounix,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,rsize=65536,wsize=130048,uid=10002,gid=1005,vers=3.0 //SMB_FOLDER LOCAL_FOLDER
```

Sometimes it happens that the SMB source is no longer available. Then I get the following error message in `messages`:

```
Dec  1 12:40:09 XXXX kernel: CIFS: VFS: \\SMB_FOLDER Send error in SessSetup = -13
Dec  1 12:40:09 XXXX kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
Dec  1 12:40:09 XXXX kernel: CIFS: VFS: \\SMB_FOLDER Send error in SessSetup = -13
Dec  1 12:40:10 XXXX kernel: CIFS: Status code returned 0xc000006d STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE
```

This error is permanently SPAMMING to the log files. Even if I unmount the folder, the error message is spammed permanently.

```
umount \\SMB_FOLDER
```

Although I unmount the folder, I cannot delete it. I get the following error message:

```
rm: removing 'LOCAL_FOLDER' is not possible: Device or resource busy
```

The following commands do not provide any output: `lsof +D LOCAL_FOLDER` and `fuser LOCAL_FOLDER` displayed.

How can I solve the problem without rebooting?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue going on now. I can't find anything.

One thing I tried that I thought was going to work but didn't have the correct ports open was: Using ssh on another Linux machine to remotely execute a

```
systemctl restart <affected log daemon/process>
```

or

```
systemctl stop <affected log daemon/process>
```

If the port you use is open on the remote server for SSH then I thought that this would work pretty nicely.

Should look something like this:

```
$ ssh -t admin@<remoteServerIP> sudo systemctl stop <neededService>
```

Edit: Be sure you use an account with required permissions to be able to work

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this happened on my VMSS running on Azure. And it was due to, when storage account/ Fileshare availability dropped from 100% to 80%. At the same time, I start getting the same error.
Even after availability was restored to 100%. the issue did not fix by itself. **I had to restart the VMSS instance to fix the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, installing `cifs-utils` package fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your credentials file "credentials=${_passwordFile}" add domain or ip address to be like

username=*user_name*

password=*your_password*

domain=*host_domain*

Comment: How does this address the question of unmounting a CIFS filesystem when the server is no longer available?